# Codeigniter Download Counter Error

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in the codeigniter.

```
if($this->userfile_model->view_file($downloadid)){                                              
                        $filedetail=$this->userfile_model->view_file($downloadid);
                        $path = 'userfiles/'.$filedetail['filename'];   
                        $companydetail=$this->company_model->view_company($companyId);
                        $create['company_info']=$companydetail['id'];
                        $create['ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
                        $create['file_info']=$filedetail['id'];                 
                        if($this->download_model->create($create)){                                                                                             
                                $this->zip->read_file($path); 
                                $this->zip->download($filedetail['filename'].'.zip');   
                                $total=$filedetail['download_count']+1;
                                $update['download_count']=$total;
                                $this->userfile_model->update($update,$filedetail['id']);
                        }
                    }
```

The above code is working. But i have one error.
For each downloading i am getting 4 counts in the database.

The file was downloading one time only but in db four records are saving with the timestamp difference of 2-4 seconds

Please tell me if my details is not clear.

Thanks to all.

Comment: I am ready to give the access details. So you can check in the live

Comment: What other code is on that page? Are you in a loop some where? What's the model look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this is a separate function in the controller called 'downloafile'. Other code is not related to that.

Comment: i dont think this because of bug in code.This may occur if browser send multiple request to the server.you can do one thing use Firebug for Firefox, crome  Inspect Element to check the net activity, you will understand whats happening  actually.

Comment: But i am checking using the post variable only. Is it possible to post multiple times automatically?

Comment: I will give the link. Can you check it ?

Comment: @SoundharRaj sure, just 'echo' any string just before the code that you insert values to the DB and another 'echo' on the function that calls this..this way you can debug.

Comment: Nope, my issue while download i am getting request more then one time.

Comment: Are you clicking the 'download' button multiple times? :) I agree with @Abin . There doesn't seem be any errors in that code.